What's happening with my Palm Tree?
I bought this palm tree a few weeks ago, and i can see mid-rib breakage in the leaflet and browning at the tips of the leaves. Also, i guess some part of it is getting droopy.
Can anyone please tell me the issue behind this and suggest me its treatment?
Also, I watered it only when the soil became dry.Here are the images anyone please help.




Drought by the looks of it - is there a drainage hole in its pot? Doesn't sound or look like you're watering well enough - the 'mid rib' damage is down to slight physical damage.
The way to water properly is to soak it thoroughly, allowing excess water to drain away through the drainage hole in the pot before replacing it in its outer pot, then making sure any more water that collects is tipped away after 30 minutes. Repeat when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch. It might need a bigger pot now or fairly soon as well.
EDIT: I forgot to ask, what soil is it potted into - is it proper potting soil?

While I'd wait to repot and shock the palm with change, would spraying help? Potted plants go from ideal rainforest greenhouses to our dry houses. Shock.

Palms do prefer a humid environment, but I never sprayed mine in the whole 20 years I had it. But I am in the UK where we have high humidity most of the time, even indoors, unless the heating is on.
